# How do I force a table row to word-break?

Tags: css, html-table

I have the following element hierarchy:

[image]

And, here is the rendering:

[image]

I want to get rid of the horizontal scroll and replace it with word break (so, not split on word boundaries).

What are the correct css settings to enable this?

Comment: Can you provide html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, what you're trying to do is get rid of the scroll bar, maintain the width and add a word break only for the `.igv-popoverValue` span which is the span on the right side. If it is you can accomplish this by floating your `.igv-popoverName` to the left and your `.igv-popoverValue` to the right and give them a width to fit on their column side, something like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3as2pbr/)

```
<td class="igv-popover-td">
    <div class="igv-popoverNameValue">
        <span class="igv-popoverName">Name</span>
        <span class="igv-popoverValue">NUP210L</span>
    </div>
</td>
```

and the CSS

```
.igv-popoverName {
    float: left;
    width: 45px;
}
.igv-popoverValue {
    word-break: break-all;
    float: right;
    width: 45px;
}
```